# Subtract control row from all other data within the same subset (Julian date) using R (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, subtraction

So far I have not been able to find a suitable solution to my problem on Stack Overflow.

I would like to use `dplyr` to subtract a control value from my data. I need to subtract the control from data measured on the same date only. There are several dates contained within my data frame, and the each date contains a different amount of data.

My data looks something like that listed below; where 'F' are the samples which need modifying and 'AC' are the controls which will be subtracted.

```
Sample  Tissue   Date       Result1     Result2
1       F      10-Jul          210         56.0
2       F      10-Jul          527        427.0
3       F      10-Jul          557         69.0
4       F      10-Jul          684        344.0
5       F      10-Jul          650         10.0
6       AC     10-Jul          200         10.0
7       F      12-Jul          676         65.0
8       F      12-Jul          520         70.0
9       F      12-Jul          595        730.0
10      AC     12-Jul          100          5.0
```

I imagine I need to use:

```
myData <- myData2 %>%
group_by(Date) %>%
```

And from there I'm a bit confused, I've tried:

```
mutate(Result1 = Result1 - subset(myData$Result1, myData$Tissue=="AC"))
```

but with no real success. I imagine there's a simple solution out there, for which I would be very grateful!

And thus I would end up with data looking something like this:

```
Sample  Tissue   Date       Result1     Result2
1       F      10-Jul           10         46.0
2       F      10-Jul          327        417.0
3       F      10-Jul          357         59.0
4       F      10-Jul          484        334.0
5       F      10-Jul          450          0.0
6       AC     10-Jul          200         10.0
7       F      12-Jul          576         60.0
8       F      12-Jul          420         65.0
9       F      12-Jul          495        725.0
10      AC     12-Jul          100          5.0
```

It would be useful if the function could be used to calculate the difference for both results or more at once. Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I've think I've found a solution with this code

`myData2 <- myData %>% 
 group_by(Date) %>%

 mutate_at(vars(3:4),funs(.-.[Tissue=="AC"]))`

Does my logic work here? Also why do I need to need  take 1 from my column number to use the `vars()` function?

Answer (score 2):

I seemed to have solved it using this code:

```
myData2 <- myData %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(3:4),funs(.-.[Tissue=="AC"]))
```

I liked the simplicity of this solution, but many thanks to the other respondents for taking time to help me out.

Comment: Your solution doesn't match your desired output, because it changes the rows where `Tissue = AC` by producing zeros. Also, you specify the position of your columns inside `mutate_at` so you have to make sure those positions won't change in the future. Also, in the end you might need to ungroup in case this affects future data manipulation.

Comment: I like the `mutate_at` solution :-) but I'd recommend:
`myData %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("Result")), funs(ifelse(Tissue=="F", .-.[Tissue=="AC"], .))) %>%
  ungroup()`

Comment: For my data at least, it's OK that the AC's end up as reading zero as they are filtered out of the data in the next step. Thanks for the improvement though!

Answer (score 0):

```
df = read.table(text = "
Sample  Tissue   Date       Result1     Result2
1       F      10-Jul          210         56.0
2       F      10-Jul          527        427.0
3       F      10-Jul          557         69.0
4       F      10-Jul          684        344.0
5       F      10-Jul          650         10.0
6       AC     10-Jul          200         10.0
7       F      12-Jul          676         65.0
8       F      12-Jul          520         70.0
9       F      12-Jul          595        730.0
10      AC     12-Jul          100          5.0
", stringsAsFactors=F, header=T)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%                                                         # for each date
  mutate(control1 = Result1[Tissue == "AC"],                                 # calculate control values
         control2 = Result2[Tissue == "AC"]) %>%
  ungroup() %>%                                                              # forget about the grouping
  mutate(Result1 = ifelse(Tissue == "F", Result1 - control1, Result1),       # update result values only for rows with tissue = F
         Result2 = ifelse(Tissue == "F", Result2 - control2, Result2)) %>%
  select(Sample:Result2)                                                     # select columns of interest

# # A tibble: 10 x 5
#   Sample Tissue   Date Result1 Result2
#    <int>  <chr>  <chr>   <int>   <dbl>
# 1      1      F 10-Jul      10      46
# 2      2      F 10-Jul     327     417
# 3      3      F 10-Jul     357      59
# 4      4      F 10-Jul     484     334
# 5      5      F 10-Jul     450       0
# 6      6     AC 10-Jul     200      10
# 7      7      F 12-Jul     576      60
# 8      8      F 12-Jul     420      65
# 9      9      F 12-Jul     495     725
# 10     10    AC 12-Jul     100       5
```

The `control` columns are used only to help you understand the process. You can use:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(Result1 = ifelse(Tissue == "F", Result1 - Result1[Tissue == "AC"], Result1),
         Result2 = ifelse(Tissue == "F", Result2 - Result2[Tissue == "AC"], Result2)) %>%
  ungroup()
```